# React-bootstrap navbar icons not obeying float

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a navbar menu with 5 items, 1 of which should be on the left and the other 4 on the right-hand side. I'm using `react-bootstrap` version `1.0.0-beta.12`

Unfortunately, all of the items appear on the left-hand side of the menu, and I can't figure out how to make them move right (despite extensive fiddling in the css). Can anyone point out where I've gone wrong, please?

This is my App `return` function:

```
return (
    <div className="App container">
      <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" className="MainNav">
        <Nav className="nav-item-left">
          <Nav.Link className="navlinkleft" as={NavLink} to="/home">1</Nav.Link>
          <Fragment><p  id='reloadtime' className="navbar-text"></p></Fragment>
        </Nav>
        <Navbar.Toggle collapseOnSelect aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse className="Boxer">
          <Nav className="RightBoxNav" >
            {this.state.isAuthenticated
              ? <Fragment>
                  <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/instructions">2</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link onClick={this.handleLogout}>3</Nav.Link>
                </Fragment>
              : <Fragment>
                  <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/instructions">2</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/confirm">3</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/signup">4</Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/login">5</Nav.Link>
                </Fragment>
            }
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
      <Routes childProps={childProps} />
    </div>
  );
```

Here's how the menu looks when on a [large screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGZc7.png). And on a [small screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdxHO.png).

A secondary problem is that the togglebutton doesn't shrink when I select a menu option, so on a small screen if I tap, say `3` then I want the right-hand menu to collapse, but it doesn't. Any ideas how to resolve that?

CSS code here:

```
.App {
    margin-top: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-nav{
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.navlinkleft{
    color: #bbb!important;
    float: left;
}

.navbar-default{
    border-color: #555;
    height:32px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.nav-link{
    color: #888!important;
    background-color: #222;
    margin-right:0px;
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    float:right;
}

.nav-link:hover{
    color: #bbb!important;
    background-color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item-left{
    background-color: #222;
    color:#888;
    float: left;
    height: 32px;
}


.navbar-text{
    color: #888!important;
    border-color: #555;
    height:32px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle!important;
}

.RightBoxNav {
    float: right!important;
    background-color: #222;
    vertical-align: middle!important;
}

.navbar-collapse .collapse .show{
    float:right;
}

.Boxer{
    float:right;

}

.MainNav {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 130%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #222;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
    line-height:35px;
    height:35px;
    width:100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 35px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-inline-start: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle!important;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler{
    float: right;
    width:32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background-color: #555;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .navbar-link{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background-color: #555;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for the current question there are few ways to approach,
all of them are from the js itself and not from css, here are some:

1. using the responsive attributes

   `<Container>
      <Row>
        <Col md={4}>md=4</Col>
        <Col md={{ span: 4, offset: 4 }}>{md={{ span: 4, offset: 4 }}} 
        </Col>
       </Row>.....`
2. using justify (and the childrens will split evenly on the navbar)

   `<Navbar className="bg-light justify-content-between">`
3. using margin auto on the left side element

   `<nav.link m="auto">leftsideelement</nav.link>.....<nav.link>will be pushed to the right</nav.link>`